# Common filter for all columns in aspxgridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, filter, devexpress, aspxgridview

I want a common filter for all columns in aspxgridview-dev express in asp.net c# like winform app. Is this possible? If yes then by which way?

Recently I have filter for each column
 [image]

But I don't want like this.
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that this is possible in dev express 14.2 version by `<SettingsSearchPanel Visible="true" />`. Hope this will be helpful to others.